# imagecopy black background

Tags: php, gd

I searched and tried all the ways i found however i couldnt managed.

What i am trying to do is : put two pregenerated(with php gd) image side by side with a space between them.

I create these two images with these lines :

```
$sideMask = imagecreatefrompng($maskFile);
imagealphablending($sideMask, false); 
imagesavealpha($sideMask, true);

$image_blank = imagecreatetruecolor($newWidth,$newHeight);

$white = imagecolorallocate($image_blank, 255, 255, 255);
imagefill($image_blank, 0, 0, $white);

imagecopy($image_blank, $ResizedSourceFile, 0, 0, 0, 0, $newWidth, $newHeight);
imagecopy($image_blank, $sideMask, $maskX, 0, 0, 0, $maskWidth, $maskHeight);

$image_blank_mask = imagecreatetruecolor($maskWidth,$maskHeight);

imagecopy($image_blank_mask, $image_blank, 0, 0, $maskX, 0, $maskWidth, $maskHeight);

return $image_blank_mask;
```

And trying to combine them with these :

```
$maxHeight = 1626;
$sideSpace = 35;

$maxWidth = 1522 + $sideSpace;

$Img01 = $Img01Created;
$Img02 = $Img02Created;

$BothSideBlank = imagecreatetruecolor($maxWidth,$maxHeight);
$white = imagecolorallocate($BothSideBlank, 255, 255, 255);
imagefill($BothSideBlank, 0, 0, $white);

imagecopy($BothSideBlank, $Img01, 0, 0, 0, 0, $maxWidth, $maxHeight);
imagecopy($BothSideBlank, $Img02, (763+$sideSpace), 0, 0, 0, $maxWidth, $maxHeight);

imagejpeg($BothSideBlank, "Test.jpg",100);
```

With this codes there is black background between images. Actually right side of the images' background is black. If i remove

```
imagecopy($BothSideBlank, $Img01, 0, 0, 0, 0, $maxWidth, $maxHeight);
```

this line background is white as i expected. But if i remove the other line and add this line. Background is black.

I have tried all things but couldnt managed it worked.

Do i miss something?

Could it be because of while generating these images?

Any help will be appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the correct size instead of ´$maxWidth´ and ´$maxHeight´ in ´imagecopy´.

```
$size01 = getimagesize($Img01);
$size02 = getimagesize($Img02);

imagecopy($BothSideBlank, $Img01, 0, 0, 0, 0, $size01[0], $size01[1]);
imagecopy($BothSideBlank, $Img02, ($size01[0]+$sideSpace), 0, 0, 0, $size02[0], $size02[1]);
```